# Re sizing and thresholding small font scanned Arabic words

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, scaling, adaptive-threshold

I am working on an arabic OCR for printed scanned documents ... Some of the scanned documents may written with font size of height 8 which is quite small ... I want to resize the height to 60 pixels but some artifacts may occur due to nature of arabic characters .. some characters may overlap .I had used local thresholding methods after resizing but the results are still not acceptable ... any ideas ?

This is an example image:

[image: Image 1]

This is the same example after resizing and applying local adaptive thresholding using 50 as a window size:

[image: Image 2]

As you can see there are some discontinuities in some characters like this one :

[image: Image 3]

Is there is any method to resize the image while preserving textual shape ?

My approach to fix characters discontinuities :

- Threshold original image before resizing using local adaptive threshold using window size of 16 (this will solve characters discontinuities but the holes in the characters are filled) call it `smallbw`.
- Resize `smallbw` using `imresize(smallbw, [nh nw], 'nearest')` and fill the holes in characters using `imfill`
- Resize the original image to height 60 pixels using `imresize(originalIm, [nh nw], 'nearest')` call it `largebw`
- Fill holes in `largebw` using `imfill` and call it `bwfill`
- Extract holes from `largebw` by `bwholes = bwfill - largebw`
- Finally, subtract `bwholes` from `smallbw` to get this

[image: Image 4]

you can see here that the discontinuity found in the character @Image 3 has been solved ... but there is another problem raised here some characters may overlap as shown here

[image: Image 5]

This is the best results I could achieve so far ... are there any other ideas that may solve these issues ?? 
and if you think this issue has no solution how would I resolve it rather than using resizing? what about using 12 font size text instead of 8?

Useful links : 
[Local adaptive threshold method used](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding)

Operating system : windows 7

Programming environment : Matlab 2013a - Image Processing toolbox

Comment: I have added in the MATLAB tag and removed one of your other tags.  If you want MATLAB followers to view your question, you need to add that tag in for better visibility!

Comment: This question is more suitable to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: try bicubic option of resize - better for enlarging -

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it belongs to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I had already posted it on dsp.stackexchange but no answers yet

Comment: If you really have to cross-post a question, at least help others find it as well with a link! And [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/20004/5687) is the crosspost on DSP-SE.

Comment: And concerning the question itself: I don't think that up-scaling the image can really help you. You just increase the dimensionality of the problem without adding any additional information.

Comment: @IbrahimAmer did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Hohenheim I'm afraid I didn't sir

Comment: @IbrahimAmer thnx , i found only paid solutions ... .